# Is combining page factory with page object pattern an anti pattern

Tags: java, selenium, page-factory

As title says. I have a piece of code, where such technique is IMO justified.

I have a page with **table**, and **each row** contains, among others, product name for which id depends on row number:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>...</td><td name ="product1">i fon</td></tr>
  <tr><td name ="product2">TV</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm finding rows with PageFactory annotation:

```
@FindBy(How= blablabla)
List<WebElement> rows;
```

Only then I know how many products are on the page, so I'm finding each product:

```
    List<String> productNames = new Vector<>();
Iterator<WebElement> itemRowsIter = rows.iterator();

    int rowIndex = 0;
    while (itemRowsIter.hasNext()) {
        By itemLocator = By.name("product" + rowIndex);
        WebElement link = quietlyFindElement(driver, itemLocator, itemRowsIter.next());
        Optional<String> text = Optional.ofNullable(link)
                .map(WebElement::getText);
        text.ifPresent(productNames::add);
        rowIndex++;
    }
```

quietlyFindElement searches for element in Selenium, catches NoSuchElementException and TimeoutException and returns null if they are thrown.

Is such solution **clean**?

Comment: Clean is subjective. If it is working the way you intend it to, I will leave it as it is.

Comment: Are you concerned that there might be a break in consecutive numbers, or will this name property always be consecutive (dynamically assigned by the app?)  If the former, I can see why you'd need a more complicated search, otherwise I could think of many simpler ways to access the product names.

Comment: The latter. Please advice a better solution, pretty please. I'm a rookie with Monads